# I can't change a variable value in object.entries foreach from parent scope

Tags: javascript, loops, scope

I want to get a boolean from an Object.entries(b).foreach but I don't know how to retrieve it.

Like :

```
const body = {a:1,b:2}
function handle() {
  let myBool = true;
  Object.entries(body).forEach(([key, value]) => {
   myBool = false;
  });
  return myBool;
}
```

So, that's always return true, I tried something like

```
const body = {a:1,b:2}
function handle() {
  return Object.entries(body).forEach(([key, value]) => {
   return false;
  });
}
```

But it doesn't work.
it's probably a lack of understanding JS, can you give me a hint ?

Comment: I tried your first piece of code and it does return false as expected. What's the issue there?

Comment: See [What does `return` keyword mean inside `forEach` function?](/q/34653612/4642212).

Comment: return Object.entries(body).forEach(...) doesn't make sense since forEach always returns undefined. If you want to return something, for example an array of booleans, use map instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `Array.prototype.map()`, `Array.prototype.forEach()` always returns `undefined` and is not chainable. The typical use case is to execute side effects at the end of a chain.

More details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach